# Why my isLocationEnabled need SuppressLint(MissingPermission) in EasyPermissions?

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

why it still need permission checker when i have used EasyPermissions?

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @AfterPermissionGranted(100)
    private fun methodRequiresTwoPermission() {
        val perms =  Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, perms)) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true // Call requires permission. @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                this, "Please allow the permission",
                100, perms
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The library you are using is not explicitly included in the Android SDK. It is a helper library developed by other developers by adding extra code.

Lint thinks that you are not requesting permissions at run-time because it doesn't see any code such as `Activity#requestPermissions()`, hence the warning.

But you can safely ignore or suppress the warning because it has been called from somewhere inside the library.